# parsing nested json with json.net

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have problems with json deserialization , below is my json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bc28c436b252c406a67f17"),
    "empname": "dhiraj",
    "empcode": "123a",
    "level": {
        "levelID": 3,
        "levelDescription": "manager",
        "levelCode": "mg"
    },
    "Address": [
        {
            "Home": {
                "streetname": "Home",
                "city": "bbb",
                "state": "aaa"
            }
        },
        {
            "Office": {
                "streetname": "ofc",
                "city": "ccc",
                "state": "ddd"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And for above json the object classes are like

```
public class Employee
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; private set; }
    public string empname { get; set; }
    public string empcode { get; set; }
    public List<Level> level { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}

public class level
{
    public string levelID { get; set; }
    public string levelDescription { get; set; }
    public string levelCode { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public List<Home> Home { get; set; }
    public List<office> Office { get; set; }
}
public class Home
{
    public string streetname { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}
public class office
{
    public string streetname { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}
```

i tried to deserialize  it using below code

```
Employee empobj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonData);
```

but got an error as

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

How can i fix it?
Is there any way, the json result is from mongodb c# query.

Comment: Well the JSON you've given isn't a `List<Employee>` - it's not an array at all. It's a *single* `Employee`. So use `DeserializeObject<Employee>`. Heck, I wouldn't expect the code you've given to even *compile*, given that you're assigning it to an `Employee` variable...

Comment: @jon : while posting it to here i made a mistake actually it is List<Employee> empobj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jsonData); this is what i am trying for  and also i have just shared one emplyee record it will be multiple in my case you can consider an array of employee record .

Comment: But the JSON you've given is simply not an array. It's a single object. That's what the deserializer is complaining about. If you add an extra `[` at the start and a `]` at the end, I suspect it'll work fine... but there's a *huge* difference between "an array with one element" and "one element".

Comment: @jon:i tried adding [ at the start and end ] to json but still same error , i think there is something wrong with my class structure according to the json

Comment: Well, you've got the same problem with address, home and office - your JSON specifies an object, but your class declares a list. It's also not clear what the `ObjectId` part of your JSON is - that part is invalid JSON, basically.

Comment: objectid is a id field of mongodb , so how should my classes look like for the given json

Comment: It's still invalid JSON. You simply can't specify a value like that in JSON. But basically your `level` (not address, sorry) property should be just a `level` rather than a `List<level>`, and your `Home` and `Office` properties should just be `Home` or `Office` rather than lists. (Ideally they shouldn't be separate classes at all...) I'll write up an answer...

Comment: @jon: rightly said as far as objectid is there it is invalid json so using another method i am converting it to valid json i am converting that to valid json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *several* problems here:

- The code you've given won't compile, as you've specified a class called `level` but used it as `Level`
- You're trying to deserialize a `List<Employee>`, but your JSON only specifies a single `Employee` object; that's not the same as an array of objects containing a single object
- Your JSON is invalid - `ObjectId("56bc28c436b252c406a67f17")` simply isn't a valid value in JSON. It may be that Json.NET has some support for this oddity, but it would be better if you could use valid JSON
- Your `Address` class specifies a `List<Home>` for the `Home` property, and likewise for the `Office` property, but again the JSON just specifies an object value, not an array. Likewise for the `level` property.

Additionally, the fact that you've got separate classes for `Home` and `Office` is pretty nasty, as is the mixture of naming conventions. The JSON structure of the addresses is far from ideal, but I guess you can't fix that.

I can't really fix the `ObjectId` problem, but I'd structure the classes as:

```
public class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("empname")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("empcode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public Level Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
    [JsonProperty("levelID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("levelDescription")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("levelCode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

// This structure is unfortunate, but imposed by the JSON
public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("Home")]
    public StreetAddress Home { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Office")]
    public StreetAddress Office { get; set; }
}

public class StreetAddress
{
    [JsonProperty("streetname")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Aside from `ObjectId`, that will parse the JSON you've given using:

```
var employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);
```

Comment: is this StreetAddress in  Address class needed i hope you missed it out while writing your answer.

Comment: @dhiraj: Sorry, yes - not sure what happened there. Have a look now.

Comment: :thanks the class structure worked for me as i am new to mongodb and c# , was trying to map mongodb document to c# classes and also no deserialization required as it being taken care by c# mongo driver and bson drivers. thanks once again